# android database issue

Tags: android, database

I am new to android.

I have an application where i am calculating the loan amount based on salary. For that I have a database of salary,Tax and medicare column. The tax and medicare depends upon the salary bracket. I want to know how to create the database and access it through the coding.

If any good sample code example is there please give the link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_the_sqlite-database_-_cursors-t319.html) you can find a simple and straight forward tutorial from anddev.

Summarize from the tutorial:

> Description: We'll need to to the
>   following things:
>
> 1. Create a DataBase (generally this is done just once)
> 2. Open the DataBase
> 3. Create a Table (generally this is done just once)
> 4. Insert some Datasets
> 5. Query for some Datasets
> 6. Close the Database

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the SQLITE database Read up on it here: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have read the [official Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/index.html). If not, there is a wealth of information about doing anything and everything you'd want on an Android device.

Since Android uses [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as it's internal database, I'd suggest reading documentation about it + the [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) part of Android guide.

These would be good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this [simple tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842) with nice graphics illustration.